# How to run an Applescript loop using a looping variable within

Tags: loops, applescript

I've scoured for an answer to this and I can't seem to find one (or at least one that I understand).

Is it possible to run an applescript loop with a looping variable within?

For example - let's say I wanted to rename each item in a list using another list:

```
    set myFirstList to {"1", "2", "3"}
    set mySecondList to {"A", "B", "C"}

    repeat with i in myFirstList
        --change '1' to 'A', change '2' to 'B', etc
        set name of i to first item of mySecondList, then second item of mySecondList, ???
    end repeat
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you want is...

```
set myFirstList to {"1", "2", "3"}
set mySecondList to {"A", "B", "C"}

set myFirstListCount to count myFirstList
repeat with i from 1 to myFirstListCount
    set item i of mySecondList to item i of myFirstList
end repeat

return {myFirstList, mySecondList}
```